# С++ Kак считать данные с консоли напечатанные асинхронным процессом?

Tags: c#, c++, c, cmd, консоль

Постановка задачи такова:
есть `C++` программа которая с помощью `COM` вызываеет мотод в `С#` dll, а та в свою очередь запускает асинхронный процесс который печатает на конcоли данные (строку).

Нужно c `C++` приложения считать эти данные с консоли

Как можно это реализовать?

Пытался использовать метод предложенный в http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/171317/ , но `С++` программа не читает с консоли то что напечатано асинхронным процессом.

Comment: А обязательно использовать консоль? Почему бы C# приложению не писать в какую-нибудь БД.

Comment: Так в том пример данные фактически берутся из памяти, вы видимо windows используете судя по COM, тогда попробуйте функцию ReadConsoleOutput

Comment: Кроме stdout есть ещё stderr.